# How to access custom fields master table in developer console

Tags: custom-field

We have integrated salesforce with our internal portal. On opportunity we have a field names Tags and there are certain values in it. When i use select Tags__c from Opportunity, i am getting only api names. How do i get the list of all labels in the Tags field? Is there a way to access the master table of the custom fields.

How to get the api name and label name in a single query?

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Tags__c is a picklist field? If so, do you want to get the labels of the picklist field instead of its API names?

Comment: Yes i want the list of labels associated with the custom field tags

Comment: then take a look to @sfdcfox's answer below

Comment: i need to retrieve both api name and label in the same query.

Comment: in the same query? Not possible. What's your purpose? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to get the api names and label so that i can import them to our internal portal sales module

Comment: Are you using a multi language org? Labels might differ based on users language settings. Additionally: do you just need all api names and all labels from this field? Or do you need for each request on opportunity the corresponding api name / label?

Comment: No we dont use multi language org. I just need all api names and labels for the field tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to be able to read *and* write the proper values, you need a describe object call (describeSObject). This is available in SOAP, REST, and the UI-API. For example, you could call `/services/v48.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe` to get the describe information.

In any case, you'll get the field and all possible API values, and their respective labels to present to a user. If you just need a translated value directly from a query (read-only access), you can use SOQL's toLabel method:

```
SELECT toLabel(Tags__c) FROM Opportunity
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have one more thing here. How do i get both api_name and labels in the same query?

Comment: @Nandy In a query, you cannot. You would need two queries. If you use the User Interface API, you can get both values at once with the Records resource, otherwise you need a describe call.